# C++ : Installing cvBlobLib library for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015, cvblobslib

I've been looking all over the web for a proper code for that library but whenever i try to build it using CMake 3.4.2 it gives me errors and when i try to build the resulting visual studio project (using Visual Studio 2015) it gives me errors as well and doesn't build successfully.

Is there any way to properly install this library and use it in Visual Studio 2015?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Screen shot of the error i get when pressing on "Generate":
[image]

Comment: The proper way is to configure and compile using CMake.

Comment: I know, that's what i did, but like i said - i couldn't find any version of the code that won't give me errors, so i was wondering if anyone knows a place i could get it from.

Comment: ***i couldn't find any version of the code that won't give me errors*** I meant for you to fix the errors or at least post them here or at github for the project to fix them. However I see from the github page that that the author has mentioned that he no longer maintains the project. https://github.com/Steelskin/cvblob/issues/1

Comment: I may be wrong, but I was under the impression that `cvBlob` was superseded by `cv::contours`...

Comment: I actually managed to get a compiled version of cvblobslib.lib but for some reason Visual Studio keeps giving me an error of not being able to open BlobResult.h

Comment: I expect that means your include path is missing a folder. You probably did not add a include_directories() in your CMakeLists.txt for your application.

Comment: I downloaded that cvblobslib.lib file from somewhere in the web, i didn't create it myself. Shouldn't it still work?

Comment: If it is a static library you may be fine (provided you have the required headers). If there is a dll it will not work (may appear to work but have UB) unless it was built for Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: i recently successfully compiled [OpenCVBlobsLib](https://github.com/OpenCVBlobsLib/opencvblobslib) with VS2015 by downloading [pthreads-win32 files](ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/dll-latest/)

Comment: could you please elaborate more on the process?

Comment: what did you try ? i downloaded [include files](ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/dll-latest/include/), [pthreadVC2.lib](ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/dll-latest/lib/x64/) and [pthreadVC2.dll](ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/dll-latest/dll/x64/) and put them in [opencvblobslib-master\library](https://github.com/OpenCVBlobsLib/opencvblobslib/tree/master/library) then enter PTHREADS_INCLUDE_DIR and PTHREADS_LIB_DIR as opencvblobslib-master\library

Comment: I just tried downloading that library from different sources around the web (i just googled it), and no matter what version of the code i downloaded, i got an error when i tried building it using CMake. I'll just follow your instructions and see if it works. Could you please provide me with a link to where you downloaded the cvBlobsLib from?

Comment: [download link of opencvblobslib](https://codeload.github.com/OpenCVBlobsLib/opencvblobslib/zip/master)

Comment: cool thanks! i'll give it a shot and let you know how it went!
just what is the PTHREADS_INCLUDE_DIR and PTHREADS_LIB_DIR you were talking about?

Comment: Those are variables you set in `cmake-gui` during the configure stage.

Comment: ohhh okay.. thanks! like i said i'll let you know asap if it worked!

Comment: still get an error.. i've edited my original post with a screenshot of what happens when i press on "Generate"

Comment: Does that path exist on your computer? Did you build opencv?

Comment: the path C:\opencv_git\mybuild\install\x86\vc14\lib\include doesn't exist but the path C:\opencv_git\mybuild\install\x86\vc14\lib exists. I did build opencv though and it works perfectly for me. So how do i change that C:\opencv_git\mybuild\install\x86\vc14\lib\include path to a path that actually exists? and what's even supposed to be there?

Comment: try setting OpenCV_DIR C:\opencv_git\mybuild

Comment: still gives me the same error :/